# Sliding submit button off screen to submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to do something like this form where the user would be able to submit the form by swiping the Submit button up or down(just touching it on the phone and then dragging it up or down of a certain threshold and it will submit the form)

Is this possible?
What do I need to do to achieve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3yOG.jpg

For instance the button can be dragged up or down and if passed a certain threshold(maybe like 50px up or down), it will AJAX the form submit

Thanks in advance!

PS: This is not what I'm working on, this is just a basic summary for a more complex concept!

Actually I'm thinking of using a mobile trick for this to work, like making the button scrollable but hide it's scrollbars but how do I actually mark the thresholds so it does something when scrolled to a certain position?

Comment: As an exercise this is fine, but you should never actually do this to your users. That is a *terrible* bit of user experience. Nobody expect to "swipe" buttons, that's not a thing you can even *do* with a button. People are going to be sitting there tapping it and wondering why it's not submitting.

Comment: Yeah it's actually something else more complex but this is just another way of putting it. Is it actually possible or how difficult would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a JavaScript problem to me. For me, I would use `jQuery` click events (`mousedown`, `mousemove`, ...) in order to recognize the dragging and then just call a callback function which submits the form and maybe gives visual feedback.

The [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) `jQuery` component might be of use for this.